# Optimizing my stored procedure - is this the right way to do it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-performance, sqlperformance

```
SELECT  TOP 1 @CurrentStudentID = StudentID
FROM    Courses WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   Courses.CourseID = @CourseID 
ORDER BY StudentID

-- Loop through all the students and find if he/she is registered for more than one course.
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND @CurrentStudentID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

    -- Select all other courses student is currently registered in.

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- return required information
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Perform some operations
    END

    -- Select the next registered student
    SELECT  TOP 1 @CurrentStudentID = StudentID
    FROM    Courses WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   Courses.CourseID = @CourseID AND
            Courses.StudentID > @CurrentStudentID 
    ORDER BY StudentID
END
```

Can someone help with my logic here? I wrote a stored procedure to find out if a student of a course is currently taking other courses from the same school.

I'm particularly worried about the two SELECT queries and the performance of a while loop if the number of students is huge. I feel the way I am doing it feels very contrived. I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

I've done SQL profiling on this stored procedure and it's duration can range from  0 - 60 ms for a single call. I don't understand why the same stored procedure's execution time is so random and inconsistent.

Appreciate any help. I only have 1 year plus of SQL Server 2008 experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL is a set-based theory language. If your entire data set is on one table, normalization isn't happening... so that's two problems with the query.

Comment: @clifton_h You're right, so after normalization, is the logic of SELECT -> While (@@rowcount > 1) { ... SELECT..} a good way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS I mentioned, SQL is a set-based theory language. In other words, it is semi-relational with data sets that allows for efficient comparisons between groups of data. "Lower" languages such as C++ or Java do not maintain such large data sets, since they are cursor (line by line) based-languages.

High level as this definition is, the point is to think of your data like `EXCEL` sheets. You have predefined columns such as `CourseID` and `StudentID`, that have information in the other columns that are dependent on those values (`CourseID` 1:1 Course_Name) and some information that is repetitive (CourseID can have multiple students).

True normalization includes removing interdependent columns, but lets not worry about that right now. The main focus is on what makes sense for the business. Your table has Identifying columns for its courses and students. So you do not need to use a cursor if those values do not have conflicting interdependent values.

```
SELECT StudentID, COUNT(COURSEID) AS CLASS_NUM
FROM   COURSES
GROUP BY StudentID
HAVING COUNT(COURSEID) > 1
```

The `GROUP BY` returns distinct sets of values from the columns listed, flattening the other rows and allowing aggregate functions like `COUNT()`. (note: `NULLS` are not counted in the `COUNT()`. Use an `ISNULL` function) 
You have not yet limited the list, and yet you achieve the same results. After SQL flattens the rows, you can use a `HAVING` clause to further limit the result sets from the `GROUP BY` if needed.

Way faster than a cursor, definitely. :)

Now, if your table includes students in different semesters and years, you might consider adding this to the `GROUP BY`, so that you have sets in your `GROUP BY` (`StudentID` and `Year`)

Also, recall that the `SELECT` statement LOGICALLY read AFTER the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, so any columns listed in the `SELECT` statement must appear in the `GROUP BY` or or have an aggregate function.

Comment: Your welcome, and now you've instantly improved your expertise in SQL, too. :) I love working with SQL, always more things to learn.